# CSV display on swings page

Tags: java

I am trying to read a csv and show it on a swings page, I am able to read but every time, it overwrites all the rows with the last row. Please help me figure out how to have all the rows displayed

```
/*View Data UI code*/
        try 
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                // use comma as separator
                  String cellValue[] = line.split(",");
                  String data[][]={{cellValue[1],cellValue[2],cellValue[3],cellValue[4],cellValue[5],cellValue[6],cellValue[7],cellValue[8]}
                  };  
                  String column[]={"Date","Shop","Item","Category","Quantity","Units","Amount","Payment"};
                  System.out.println(data);
                  JTable jt = new JTable(data,column);
                  jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(jt.getPreferredSize());
                 // jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                  sp=new JScrollPane(jt);
                }
            }

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (br != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    br.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        /*End of Data UI Code*/
```

Comment: I am trying to read a csv and show it on a swings page, I am able to read but every time, it overwrites all the rows with the last row. Please help me figure out how to have all the rows displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you create a new `JTable` for every run of your loop. That would explain why you only see the last row.

Comment: Reinlander: Thank You for your reply, I am trying your pointer, I will update you asap

Comment: I tried declaring String data[][],String column[] and moved the following lines:
JTable jt = new JTable(data,column);
jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(jt.getPreferredSize());
sp=new JScrollPane(jt); out side while loop but its not working:(

Comment: I want to post my complete code but I'm not able edit my question and can't ask a new question:(

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is it the same problem as before?

Comment: @Dharamveer seems you may be overwriting your `data[][]` as well.. you may want to create a new array `data[rowCount] = new String() { columns.. } `   once you got it working , you may want to read a [TableModel tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) as well

Comment: @gusto2: Thank you for your input, I will try this and will update you once I fix this.